# Constructor getting called twice React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, react-router, react-redux

The constructor of my react component is getting called twice but I can't figure out why. I am using react-redux to store the language of my app. I have a function that set the default language base on browser's language. **LoginPage** is the first component that gets render so I called my function in its constructor. Basically what it does is compare and dispatch an action. When I checked my state with redux developer tools I saw that it was getting dispatched twice. I printed dummy data in the constructor and it gets printed twice too.

LoginPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {startLogin} from '../actions/auth';
import {setLanguage} from '../actions/lang';

export class LoginPage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.setDefaultLanguage();
    console.log('i am constructor');
  }

  changeLanguage = (e) => {
    const lan = e.target.value;
    this.props.setLanguage(lan);
  };

  setDefaultLanguage = () => {
    const defaultLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en-US';

    if(defaultLanguage == 'es'){
      this.props.setLanguage(defaultLanguage);
    }else{
      this.props.setLanguage('en');
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="box-layout">
        <div className="box-layout__box">
          <h1 className="box-layout__title">Expensify</h1>
          <p>It\'s time to get your expenses under control.</p>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.props.startLogin}>Log in with google</button>
          <select className="select" onChange={this.changeLanguage}>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="es">Español</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startLogin: () => dispatch(startLogin()),
  setLanguage: (language) => dispatch(setLanguage(language))
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)( LoginPage);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import ExpenseDashBoardPage from '../components/ExpenseDashBoardPage';
import AddExpensePage from '../components/AddExpensePage';
import EditExpensePage from '../components/EditExpensePage';
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute';

export const history = createHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={ExpenseDashBoardPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>

  </Router>
)

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Check once if you have enabled the Strict mode. As in strict mode react constructor is called twice. For more info check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575784/8454203

Comment: NOTE: Only happens in Development mode, wont happen in production mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321562/984471

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should not call Redux actions or any kind of AJAX from within the constructor. Those things should be done in `componentDidMount()`.

Second, I would request the language from the store as part of props. If not defined, then in `componentDidMount()` call your `setDefaultLanguage()`.

I would do at least the following:

```
export class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.lang) {
        this.setDefaultLanguage();
    }
  }

  changeLanguage = (e) => {
    const lan = e.target.value;
    this.props.setLanguage(lan);
  };

  setDefaultLanguage = () => {
    const defaultLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en-US';

    if(defaultLanguage == 'es'){
      this.props.setLanguage(defaultLanguage);
    }else{
      this.props.setLanguage('en');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="box-layout">
        <div className="box-layout__box">
          <h1 className="box-layout__title">Expensify</h1>
          <p>It\'s time to get your expenses under control.</p>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.props.startLogin}>Log in with google</button>
          <select className="select" onChange={this.changeLanguage}>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="es">Español</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    // Assuming `steate.lang` is where you would set the language.
    lang: state.lang
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startLogin: () => dispatch(startLogin()),
  setLanguage: (language) => dispatch(setLanguage(language))
});

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps) => ({ ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Thanks . Could you provide any source to support your statement "you should not call Redux actions or any kind of AJAX from within the constructor. " I would like to know why

Comment: Yeah, here are the links: https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1, https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue because I was redirecting the user inside my public routes. So it was rendering the component twice. In case you are using

```
history.push('/');
```

This is going to render the component twice.

Answer (score 4):

This twice calling some of the lifecycle methods, is only for development mode.

**"Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode."**

Answer (score 4):

Yep. It’s intentional and documented here. It only happens in development mode.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Answer (score 3):

If you check React Dev Tools of what is being rendered you'll see something like `connect(App)` as well as `App` by itself, so your console.log will be called twice. This is because connect is a higher order component.

If you move `this.setDefaultLanguage()` (and your `console.log` so you can see it in action) out of the constructor and into the `componentDidMount` life cycle hook, it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution : Replace "React.StrictMode" by "<>" in your index.js**

**Reason: **
It is important that state and lifecycle methods  do not contains side effects. Ignoring this rule can lead to a variety of problems, including memory leaks and invalid application state. Unfortunately, it can be difficult to detect these problems as they can often be non-deterministic.

**Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:**

1. constructor
2. render
3. shouldComponentUpdate
4. getDerivedStateFromProps
5. Function component bodies
6. State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
7. Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

**This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode.**

Comment: This was the only solution given and should be voted up.  You gave good details to why it is used and how to turn it off.

Comment: @Exzile Glad to know you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Development mode can be disabled using the following code in **index.js**

```
//  <React.StrictMode>
    <Application />
//  </React.StrictMode>
```