# React calls constructor twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to develop a simple web app with it but I get an error.
My Constructor is called twice when I load a class component can you help?

```
Home.js


import React from 'react'
import Land from "../Land";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home!</h1>
            <Land/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

```
Partial Land.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Login from "./Login";

class Land extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

        }
        console.log("LAND")
    }
```

the log LAND is hit twice.
In some of the components I wish to make an API call that hits a DB but I only want to hit it once.
In many instances using `componentDidMount` is not convenient because props only appear after `componentDidMount` therefor id like to do the call in `render`(I will not be using setState, that would cause a reload of render).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor getting called twice React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644387/constructor-getting-called-twice-react-component)

Comment: @Temoncher I've read that topic but I am still confused, They recommend the use of ```componentDidMount```. but when I can not call a function component from a class component within ```componentDidMount```

Comment: Maybe you're rendering `Home` twice? And no, you definitely should not do API calls in the constructor. You'll need to re-render anyway after asynchronous response.

Comment: @Bergi I put a log on home and it was hit only once.
BTW, is it ok to put api calls on ```componentDidMount```?

Comment: For example in this function component, it is called twice, once where the props aren't loaded and after that one where the props are loaded.
I use the props to construct the api url and if the prop is "" i get a different api call that returns wrong data
```function EventProps(props) {
    console.log(props.event_id);
    if (props.event_id == "")
        return (<h1>Hold up</h1>)
    const url = "/events/"+props.event_id;
    console.log(url);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are using `<StrictMode/>` and it's development mode

While in `<StrictMode/>`, react will [detect unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) which will call lifecycle functions more than once duration the development mode, will not be trigger twice in production.

#### From docs:

#### why is called twice

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
>
> Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
>
> Function component bodies
>
> State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
>
> Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

#### will not call twice

> Note:
>
> This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode.

Comment: Will my production still be in strict mode?

Comment: OK, I see what you are talking about, the answer is no, this has been figure out in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get what are you trying to say in the comment, but you totally can call function that fetches data within `componentDidMount` hook

Here's an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-calls-constructor-twice-q5gzs

Comment: Ohhhhh now i see what you mean.
So would you recommend using class components for components with api calls?
And if so i should put the result of said api call on state so the render can "rerender" when the call is complete?

Thanks for your time!